# Unable to display value in the inputfield using material-ui-color-picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My objective is to display the color value in the input field. I couldn't able to get the color value in the textfield. Can anyone help me in this Query to get the color value which should accept only hexa color values?

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import ColorPicker from "material-ui-color-picker";

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: ""
    };
  }
  handleColor = (e) => {
    console.log("color", e);
    this.setState({ color: e });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ColorPicker
        name="color"
        defaultValue={this.state.color}
        onChange={this.handleColor}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is the sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-breeze-l0k20)
Can anyone please help me in this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the `value` prop to reflect the color you're saving in your state. [Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-wave-vtsm5) a corrected sandbox.

This component behaves strangely in that it doesn't seem to display the hex value of the color when a new one is selected, only change the color of the text itself. According to its docs, it was designed to work with the `redux-form` package, so it may only exhibit more expected behavior in conjunction with that package, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/hute3?file=/src/styles.css, hope this will solve your problem, this sandbox is exactly what you have been looking for.

Comment: i want to save the value in the state variable. Could you please help me in that